# Error installing npm grunt-libsass

Tags: gruntjs, npm, libsass

I'm trying to install grunt-libsass like this:

```
npm install grunt-libsass --save-dev
```

but I get this error:

```
npm WARN engine grunt-libsass@0.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.10.27"} (current: {"node":"5.1.1","npm":"3.3.12"})
npm WARN engine grunt-libsass@0.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.10.27"} (current: {"node":"5.1.1","npm":"3.3.12"})
npm WARN deprecated grunt-libsass@0.2.1: No longer maintained

> node-sass@0.9.6 install /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tome/wp-content/node_modules/node-sass
> node build.js

(node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/binding/binding.o
In file included from ../binding.cpp:1:
../../nan/nan.h:189:68: error: too many arguments to function call, expected at most 2, have 4
    return v8::Signature::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), receiver, argc, argv);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/goliathus/.node-gyp/5.1.1/include/node/v8.h:4674:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Signature> New(
  ^
In file included from ../binding.cpp:1:
../../nan/nan.h:271:3: error: redefinition of 'NanNew'
```

what does the error say and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [grunt-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass) instead of grunt-libsass because it is no longer maintained.

> This task uses libsass which is a Sass compiler in C++.

Comment: This doesn't work, output is the same as above. Here is a gist of the error, https://gist.github.com/alphapilgrim/3b4c3255a8b693c7e5814f28ab5dd7bf.